# Entityframework getting error for saving relationship entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Problem**

I have three model classes Student,Job and Alumni. I created EF DB first approah and I was able to save the Alumni details,But facing the error while saving the Student and Job details.Attached the relationship edmx file for reference.

**Issue :**
I am facing the error like "An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code" when crearing a new record for Job and Student.

**Outcome:**
I need to save new records for jobs and students from the EF,I was able to save alumni details

**Clarification:**
Is there any way to check the query being executed to SQL server from Visual Studio in entity framework other than profiler

**JobController:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="JCompanyName,JobType,JDesignation,JElgibility,JLocation,JYearOfPassed,JPercentReq,JDescription,JAddress,JSalary,JLastDateToApply,JNumberOfVaccancy,JHiringRounds,IsActive,IsCompany")] Job job)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Jobs.Add(job);
                db.SaveChanges(); //Facing the issue here for jobs and Student 
                                  //controller
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Alumni_ID = new SelectList(db.Alumni, "Id", "AName", job.Alumni_ID);
            return View(job);
        }
```

**Job Model:**

```
  public partial class Job
    {
        public Job()
        {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Alumni_ID { get; set; }
        public string JCompanyName { get; set; }
        public string JobType { get; set; }
        public string JDesignation { get; set; }
        public string JElgibility { get; set; }
        public string JLocation { get; set; }
        public int JYearOfPassed { get; set; }
        public int JPercentReq { get; set; }
        public string JDescription { get; set; }
        public string JAddress { get; set; }
        public string JSalary { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime JLastDateToApply { get; set; }
        public int JNumberOfVaccancy { get; set; }
        public string JHiringRounds { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsCompany { get; set; }

        public virtual Alumnus Alumnus { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

**Student Model:**

```
public partial class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Job_Id { get; set; }
        public string Sname { get; set; }
        public string Sphone { get; set; }
        public string SEmail { get; set; }
        public string SAddress { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        public string StudyType { get; set; }
        public string CollegeOrBoard { get; set; }
        public decimal SchoolPercent { get; set; }
        public string SchoolState { get; set; }
        public string SchoolCity { get; set; }
        public string Skills { get; set; }
        public string SkillLevel { get; set; }
        public string IntermediateName { get; set; }
        public string IntermediateStudyType { get; set; }
        public string IntermediateBoard { get; set; }
        public string IntermediatePercent { get; set; }
        public string IntermediateState { get; set; }
        public string IntermediateCity { get; set; }
        public string UGName { get; set; }
        public string UGStream { get; set; }
        public string UGStudyType { get; set; }
        public string UGBoard { get; set; }
        public string UGPercent { get; set; }
        public string UGState { get; set; }
        public string UGCity { get; set; }

        public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
    }
```

**Alumns Model:**

```
public partial class Alumnus
    {
        public Alumnus()
        {
            this.Jobs = new HashSet<Job>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AName { get; set; }
        public string ACompany { get; set; }
        public string APhone { get; set; }
        public string AEmail { get; set; }
        public string AAddress { get; set; }
        public string ACompanyAddress { get; set; }
        public int ABatchYear { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
```

**SQL Script:**

```
USE [AlumniConnect]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Alumni]    Script Date: 05/04/2019 21:57:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Alumni](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ACompany] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [APhone] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [AEmail] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [AAddress] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ACompanyAddress] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ABatchYear] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Jobs]    Script Date: 05/04/2019 21:57:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Jobs](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Alumni_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JCompanyName] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [JobType] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [JDesignation] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [JElgibility] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [JLocation] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [JYearOfPassed] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JPercentReq] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [JAddress] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [JSalary] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [JLastDateToApply] [date] NOT NULL,
    [JNumberOfVaccancy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JHiringRounds] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [IsCompany] [bit] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Student]    Script Date: 05/04/2019 21:57:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Job_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sname] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Sphone] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [SEmail] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SAddress] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [StudyType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CollegeOrBoard] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolPercent] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolState] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolCity] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Skills] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [SkillLevel] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [IntermediateName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [IntermediateStudyType] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [IntermediateBoard] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [IntermediatePercent] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [IntermediateState] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [IntermediateCity] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UGName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UGStream] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UGStudyType] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UGBoard] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UGPercent] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UGState] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UGCity] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SEmail] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Sphone] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Jobs_fk0]    Script Date: 05/04/2019 21:57:36 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Jobs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Jobs_fk0] FOREIGN KEY([Alumni_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Alumni] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Jobs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Jobs_fk0]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Student_fk0]    Script Date: 05/04/2019 21:57:36 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Student]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Student_fk0] FOREIGN KEY([Job_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Jobs] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Student] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Student_fk0]
GO
```

[image: Relationship between Job,Student and Alumni]

Answer (score 0):

The pattern of saving here matters because of db dependencies

Try This

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
//I removed the binding so the answer can be clearer, you can still include it but you need to pass the models. I don't know if you have passed them before
public ActionResult Create(Job job, Student student, Alumni alumni)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //you will have to save in this pattern Alumni first, Job second, Student last
        db.Alumni.Add(alumni);
        db.SaveChanges(); 
        //save the job
        job.Alunmi_ID = alumni.Id
        db.Job.Add(job)
        db.SaveChanges()
        //save the student
        student.Job_ID = job.Id
        db.Student.Add(student)
        db.SaveChanges()

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

        ViewBag.Alumni_ID = new SelectList(db.Alumni, "Id", "AName", job.Alumni_ID);
        return View(job);
    }
```